# beamer/tikz overlay image at the center

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, animations

How can I overlay in tikz an image at the center of the slide, covering the text.

Consider:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \pause
  \node (img1) {\rule{3cm}{2cm}};
  \pause
  \node (img2) at (img1.south east) {\rule{3cm}{2cm}};
  \pause
  \node (img3) at (img2.south west) [yshift=1cm] {\rule{3cm}{2cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: I would to center this]

I would like the image animation to appear in the center of the slide.

**Bonus points** if you can cover the entire slide in a gray color to highlight the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? I used the `current page.` family of nodes (I used some opacity; adjust the settings according to your needs):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \pause
  \fill[gray!80,opacity=0.8]
  (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \pause
  \node (img1) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
  \pause
  \node (img2) at (img1.south east) {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
  \pause
  \node (img3) at (img2.south west) [yshift=1cm] {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```